# Content-Length is returning null , how can i get this fixed

Tags: javascript, php

can you see any reason why i'm returning null for "size" ?  On one of my servers its returning the correct file size , on my other server i get "null"

snippets below

```
function convertFileSize(size){
        console.log(size);
    var _size=parseInt(size);
    if(_size<1000) return _size+"b";
    if(_size<1000000) return (_size/1000).toFixed(1)+"kb";
    if(_size<1000000000) return (_size/1000000).toFixed(2)+"mb";
    return (_size/1000000000).toFixed(2)+"gb";
}

function fetchHeader(yr, which) {
    try {
        var url = '<?php echo $year."/leagues/".$league_id."/"; ?>';
        url+= yr+".js";
        var req=new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open("HEAD", url, false);
        req.send(null);
        if(req.status===200){
            return req.getResponseHeader(which);
        } else 
            return "";
    } catch(er) {
        return er.message;
    }
}


html+='<td id="file_size_'+my_data[yearKey]['yid']+'" class="file_size">'+convertFileSize(fetchHeader(my_data[yearKey]['yid'],'Content-Length'))+'</td>';
```

Comment: Have you done any debugging? What's the result of the `HEAD` request?

Comment: Most likely the servers are configured differently. Does the server that is not sending Content-Length also send Transfer-Encoding?

Comment: You may find this helpful: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-3.3.2

Comment: anyone know a different way to get the file size since one of my servers obviously doesn't like Content_Length